# If else using for setting class

Tags: php, class, if-statement

I want to set every first and second `tr` with a different class.
With my code I only get "odd" on every tr.
Does anyone knew what is wrong?

```
 $rowCount = 0;
 if ($rowCount++ % 2 == 1 ) :
     echo "<tr class='even'>";
 else:
     echo "<tr class='odd'>";
 endif;
```

Comment: Well from just that code, it looks like you are setting `$rowCount = 0` every time. Can you provide a bit more information. Also, why wouldn't you just use a conditional operator? e.g. `echo '<tr class="' . (($rowCount++ % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd') . '>'`

Comment: I find out what i have done wrong. I put the $rowCount = 0; in the while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one (keep the $rowCount setting outside the loop):

```
for($row = 0; $row < $rowTotal; $row++)
{
   echo "<tr class='".($row % 2 ? "even" : "odd")."'>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic implementation is going in wrong direction

```
$rowCount = 0;//This was always initializing your count to 0
```

Resulting always odd class added

Change it to this:

```
for ($rowCount = 0;$rowCount<$total; $rowCount++) {
    if ($rowCount % 2 == 1 ) :
        echo "<tr class='even'>";
    else:
        echo "<tr class='odd'>";
    endif;
}
```

OR you can simply use `ternary` operator as

```
for ($rowCount=0; $rowCount<$total; $rowCount++) {
    echo "<tr class='".($rowCount % 2 == 0 )?'odd':'even'."'>";
}
```

Comment: the for loop has an error in your code. actually the error is in the loop body: remove the additional ++ (in the ternary-op expression), since having it twice will increment twice the number per iteration.